# Apache Airflow : How to write a custom sensor that checks for a certain condition and performs operation

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-2.x

I want to write a custom sensor in Airflow 2. The standard procedure is to override the poke method to check for the condition you want and terminate the task when it is reached. But what i want is for my sensor to initially perform an operation, and then sleep and check for a certain condition.

How can i do this by overriding the poke method. The operation i want to perform must happen only once but during every poking interval the poke method runs for checking the condition. How can i implement this without overriding the execute method?

Comment: I would split this up into two tasks: one operator which runs the once-off task, and next the sensor checking the condition.

Comment: @BasHarenslak But what if I needed just one sensor. Then what would be a better way to approach it